# Assign class using python dictionary filters

Tags: python, django

I want to add class according to index if dictionary key is found in my list

```
`area_stats = {'85': (True, False, False, False, False), '11': (False, False, False, False, True)} `
```

which the dictionary keys area arrange as `top,right,bottom,left,center`

```
  {% with '18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28' as list_upper %}`
  {% for x in list_upper.split %}
  <td><svg width="50" height="50" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="10.8px" height="7.6px" viewBox="0 0 10.8 7.6" style="width:100%; enable-background:new 0 0 10.8 7.6;" xml:space="preserve">
<ellipse   name="centerArea_{{ x }}" class="{% if area_stat[center]==true, highlight, no_highlight %}" />
<path  name="leftArea_{{ x }}" class="class="{% if area_stat[left]==true, highlight, no_highlight %}""/>`
<path name="topArea_{{ x }}" class="{% if area_stat[top]==true, highlight, no_highlight %}"/>`
<path  name="bottomArea_{{ x }}" class="{% if area_stat[bottom]==true, highlight, no_highlight %}"/><path  name="rightArea_{{ x }}" class="{% if area_stat[right]==true, highlight, no_highlight %}"/></svg>
</td>
{% endfor %}
 </tr>
{% endwith %}`
```

is this possible in django? What I tried so far is to use dictionary filters but I don't have idea how to display dictionary values according to index.

```
@register.filter(name='is_dict_key')
def is_dict_key(key, d):
   return key in d
@register.filter(name='get_dict_value')
def get_dict_value(d, key):
  try:
      return d[key]
  except KeyError as e:
      print(e)
      return None`
```

Comment: 4 spaces at the start of the line will format your code correctly. You are more likely to get people reading the question.

Comment: you should indent your code blocks with 4 spaces, or you can highlight your code and hit `ctrl`+`k` to do it automatically for you... please edit your question

Comment: What are "area_stat", "center", "left" and "right" ???

Comment: `area_stat` the given values that I want to show inside `for loop` .  My example `{'11': (True, False, False, False, False),` means, show the boolean values which are arranged by `top, right, bottom, left, center` if the value `11` is found in `list_upper` loop. thank you for your response.